# Why is my controller action returning 404?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a controller action called by an ajax call and it keeps returning a 404 error.

My Action:

```cs
[HttpGet("~/TIB/Forms/GetGtmGrid")]
public IEnumerable<object> GetGtmGrid(int? id)
{
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DB")))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        
        SqlDataAdapter sqlData = new SqlDataAdapter("usp_GetGTMNotesById", sqlConnection);
        
        sqlData.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlData.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", id);
        
        sqlData.Fill(dtbl);
    }

    List<GTMNote> gtmNotes = new List<GTMNote>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dtbl.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        gtmNotes.Add(new GTMNote
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(dtbl.Rows[i]["Id"]),
            Text = dtbl.Rows[i]["Text"].ToString(),
            ProjectId = Convert.ToInt32(dtbl.Rows[i]["ProjectId"]),                   
            Date = (DateTime)dtbl.Rows[0]["Date"],
            StatusId = Convert.ToInt32(dtbl.Rows[i]["StatusId"])
        });
    }

    GTMNote[] gtmArray = gtmNotes.ToArray();

    return gtmArray;
}
```

AJAX call:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/TIB/Forms/GetGtmGrid",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    //Pass parameters to controller
    data: { id: id }
})
```

Here is the 404 error link:

> GET `https://localhost:<port>/TIB/Forms/GetGtmGrid?id=428` 404

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. My controller actions and ajax calls are set up like all my other ones and they work just fine.

Comment: `localhostxxxxx` should be `localhost:<port>` shouldn't it?

Comment: @Andy It is, I just put the x cause I'm tired and wasn't really thinking....

Comment: Never seen a ~ in a HttpGet attribute

Comment: Try to change your attribute to "/TIB/Forms/GetGtmGrid/{id?}" And your Ajax call with /id instead of parameter url

Comment: @GHDevOps check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis-1

Comment: @NerdyDriod can you show the controller class definition including any route attributes?

Comment: You get a 404 because ASP Core doesn't find any matching route. Enable debug logging and take a look what logging tells you.

Comment: With a localhost url, I assume you call that api from the same computer the api is running on? Does that url work directly from a browser?

Comment: Hi @NerdyDriod, In ASP.NET,'HttpGetAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments. Did you use ASP.NET Core? But in ASP.NET Core this also work fine. Did you try postman or browser send get request to the api?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was causing the issue. It was the routing, ("~/TIB/Forms/GetGtmGrid"), in the action verb I was using with my controller action. So I changed my action verb from [HttpGet("~/TIB/Forms/GetGtmGrid")] to [HttpGet] and it worked as expected.